# Serialise choice text for IntegerField with choices

Tags: django-rest-framework

I'd like to serialise a model with a lot of choices like such:

```
class House(models.Model):
ACCESSIBILITY_CHOICES = (
    (ACCESSIBILITY_FULL, 'Full'),
    (ACCESSIBILITY_PARTIAL, 'Partial'),
    (ACCESSIBILITY_NONE, 'None')
)

accessibility = models.IntegerField(max_length=1, choices=ACCESSIBILITY_CHOICES, null=True)
```

I love that the default serializer such as:

```
class HouseView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    model = House
    serializer_class = HouseSerializer

class HouseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = House
```

works great if I want just the integer value

```
{accessibility:1}
```

However, what I'd like to get

```
{accessibility:'Full'}
```

Help is kindly appreciated. 
Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the choices in the serializer field with the raw values like so...

```
ACCESSIBILITY_CHOICES = (
    ('Full', 'Full'),
    ('Partial', 'Partial'),
    ('None', 'None')
)
```

Then take a look at overriding the 'to_native' method so that the string values get translated into their integer equivalents.

That should give you an external API that uses the string representations, but a backend that uses the integer representations.

**Update 2019:** DRF now uses different method name to convert from/to internal, see [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#examples). to name them: `to_representation` and `to_internal_value`, instead of `to/from_native`.

Comment: Ok, cool. Thanks for looking at this. Good I checked there wasn't a more declarative solution to overwriting to_native.

Answer (score 13):

You can get a *read-only* serializer field with the verbose value of a model field with choices through the [`get_FOO_display`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display) method. This method is added automatically when setting choices on a field. You can set that method as the source for a character field.

For endpoints that also support writing data, I would recommend to add the "normal" field, and another read-only field with the `_name` extension.

In your example, the following should produce the output you are looking for. The `accessibility_name` is read-only, while the `accessibility` is there to allow writing / updating values.

```
class HouseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    accessibility_name = serializers.CharField(source='get_accessibility_display')

    class Meta:
        model = House
        fields = ('accessibility', 'accessibility_name', )
```