# Django Rest Framework: get_FOO_display in serializer not letting me POST

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I recently added a `source='get_fieldname_display` to my serializer. It worked perfectly for the purpose of obtaining the display value of a `choices` tuple but now I can no longer POST data using the API end point without getting an error:

```
TypeError: 'get_fieldname_display' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

To be clear, the addition to the serializer was this line specifically:

```
fieldName = serializers.CharField(source='fieldName_display')
```

I know that this line is causing the problem because when I comment it out, I can POST data without a problem. However, I need this line in there so I may obtain the display names from the `choices` tuple when I am GETting data.

I think the problem may be remedied if I use two different serializers, one for GET and another for POST, but I am not sure how to go about doing this--I am using a `generics.ListCreateAPIView` in my views.py.

EDIT:

My model looks like this:

```
class MakeObjects(models.Model):

    FIELD_NAME_CHOICES = (
        ("01", "Choice 1"), 
        ("02", "Choice 2"), 
    )

    fieldname = CharField(choices = FIELD_NAME_CHOICES)
```

My serializer looks like this:

```
class ObjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): 
       fieldname = serializers.CharField(source='get_fieldname_display')
       class Meta:
           model = MakeObjects
           fields = ('__all__')
```

Comment: Your fieldName in models.py is an IntegerField with choices?

Comment: You can set that particular field as `required=False`

Comment: I do not think the problem is with the model, I think it is with the serializer. Basically, my goal is to render the "get_FOO_display" as JSON--but in so doing by adding the line of code mentioned in my question--I can no longer POST data using the same serializer. Maybe a quick-fix is to use two different serializers? One for the get and another for post? I am not sure how to go about that though.

Comment: @VijeshVenugopal, I added `required=False` to the serializier, but the model I am using requires that field in order to create a new object--which is what I am doing when I POST. My bad, I should have specified that upfront.

Comment: seems similar to your's https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20107471/serialise-choice-text-for-integerfield-with-choices

Comment: Similar but not the same problem--my problem is that I cannot POST data without getting the error mentioned in my question.

Comment: Could you please try replacing **fieldname** with any other name as I couldn't figure out any issue in your code?

Comment: That's okay. I just solved the problem by creating another view and another serializer. Bit messy but works.

Comment: Creating two different serializers and consequently two different views for each GET and POST, while having just a single model, is a terrible approach. Please check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34534239/return-display-name-in-choicefield, it might give you an idea about an alternative approach.

Answer (score 2):

To achieve that, you need custom serializer field.

Here's the snippet for python 3:

```
class DisplayNameWritableField(serializers.ChoiceField):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.html_cutoff = kwargs.pop('html_cutoff', self.html_cutoff)
        self.html_cutoff_text = kwargs.pop('html_cutoff_text', self.html_cutoff_text)

        self.allow_blank = kwargs.pop('allow_blank', False)
        super(ChoiceField, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def to_representation(self, value):
        return self.choices.get(value, value)

    def bind(self, field_name, parent):
        super().bind(field_name, parent)
        self.choices = parent.Meta.model._meta.get_field(field_name).choices
```

Then:

```
class YourModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    your_choiced_model_field = DisplayNameWritableField()
```

This is a bit hacky though, so not all auto-docs engines detect choices correctly, even though this works pretty well.

You might also like https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/1755

Answer (score 0):

you can try adding the new field in:

```
read_only_fields = ['fieldName']
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone this might still help, my favorite approach is to create a new field altogether to display the human readable name, and make the new field read only.

Your serializer now looks something like

```
class ObjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): 
   fieldname_full = serializers.CharField(source='get_fieldname_display')
   class Meta:
       model = MakeObjects
       fields = ('fieldname', 'fieldname_full')
       read_only_fields = ('fieldname_full',)
```

Your response then looks like

```
{
    "country": "GM",
    "country_full": "The Gambia"
}
```

You have one field with a short, unambiguous value that's great for create and update operations, and another that's read only and human readable.